# Python re.sub with raw string prefix replacing 10 with H and 20 with P

Tags: python, regex

I'm building some templating into my app that takes a string like this:

```
templateString = r'{title} {- author} ({timestamp})'
```

And replaces the appropriate string (if it exists) inside the template {}:

```
# 10 things on my todo list - Brandon (2018-01-01 00:00:01)
```

I want to allow custom chars inside the template strings so that the user can hyphenate or bracketize or whatever, but only if those properties exist, e.g. if author is empty, you don't want to see:

```
# 10 things on my todo list -  (2018-01-01 00:00:01)
```

You want to see:

```
# 10 things on my todo list (2018-01-01 00:00:01)
```

To do this, I'm trying to use capture groups to grab any text that exists between `{`, the identifying word, and `}`:

```
titleExp = re.compile(r'\{([^\{]*)title([^\}]*)\}', re.I)
authorExp = re.compile(r'\{([^\{]*)author([^\}]*)\}', re.I)
timestampExp = re.compile(r'\{([^\{]*)timestamp([^\}]*)\}', re.I)
```

What's super strange, is that when I try to replace using a raw string, `r'\1{}\2'`), instead of "10 things on my todo list", I get "H things on my todo list":

```
templateString = r'{title} {- author} ({timestamp})'
self.title = "10 things on my todo list"
renamed = re.sub(titleExp, (r'\1{}\2' if self.title else '').format(self.title or ''), renamed)
# H things on my todo list ...
```

I of course tried without a raw string:

```
templateString = r'{title} {- author} ({timestamp})'
self.title = "10 things on my todo list"
renamed = re.sub(titleExp, ('\\1{}\\2' if self.title else '').format(self.title or ''), renamed)
# 10 things on my todo list ...
```

But the same thing happens.

What's going on? Why are the raw strings goofing up? I can tell that it's got something to do specifically with numbers, and likely the capture groups not behaving correctly.

---

End to end to reproduce:

```
templateString = r'{title} {- author} ({timestamp})'

titleExp = re.compile(r'\{([^\{]*)title([^\}]*)\}', re.I)
authorExp = re.compile(r'\{([^\{]*)author([^\}]*)\}', re.I)
timestampExp = re.compile(r'\{([^\{]*)timestamp([^\}]*)\}', re.I)

title = "10 things on my todo list"
author = "Brandon"
timestamp = "2018-01-01 00:00:01"

templateString = re.sub(titleExp, r'\1{}\2'.format(title), templateString)
templateString = re.sub(authorExp, r'\1{}\2'.format(author), templateString)
templateString = re.sub(timestampExp, r'\1{}\2'.format(timestamp), templateString)

print(templateString)

# output:
# H things on my todo list - Brandon (P18-01-01 00:00:01)
# ^ ??                                ^ ??

# expected:
# 10 things on my todo list - Brandon (2018-01-01 00:00:01)
```

More research:

It appears to be related to the *first* character of the replacement strings:

```
title = " 10 things on my todo list"
#.       ^ space
author = "Brandon"
timestamp = " 2018-01-01 00:00:01"
#.       ^ space
```

Fixes it... sort of...

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `"-"` outside the `{author}` placeholder and then use `re.sub`:

```
import re
templateString = r'{title} - {author} ({timestamp})'
title = "10 things on my todo list"
author = "Brandon"
timestamp = "2018-01-01 00:00:01"
new_data = re.sub('-\s(?=\{author)', '', templateString).format(title=title, author=author, timestamp = timestamp) if not author else templateString.format(title=title, author=author, timestamp = timestamp)
print(new_data)
```

Output:

```
10 things on my todo list - Brandon (2018-01-01 00:00:01)
```

When `author` is empty:

```
title = "10 things on my todo list"
author = ""
timestamp = "2018-01-01 00:00:01"
new_data = re.sub('-\s(?=\{author)', '', templateString).format(title=title, author=author, timestamp = timestamp) if not author else templateString.format(title=title, author=author, timestamp = timestamp)
print(new_data)
```

Output:

```
10 things on my todo list  (2018-01-01 00:00:01)
```

Comment: That would be great if I always knew what to look for, but if the template changes, I no longer know what is safe to replace or not. E.g. `{title}_{author}_` or `{title} ({author})`.

Comment: @brandonscript in that case, what would your desired output be for each? For example, if the template is `'{title}_{author}_({timestamp})'` and no author is given, would the output be `'{title} {author}_({timestamp})'`?

Comment: `'{title}_{author}_({timestamp})'` would become 'Title replaced string_(timestamp)'`. This is why I need the optional chars inside the `{}` template, e.g. `'{title}{_author}_({timestamp})'`.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if I break out the expression without using inline capture groups, it behaves correctly. I can use this as a workaround for now, but I sure would love an explanation for why...

```
templateString = r'{title} {- author} ({timestamp})'

titleExp = re.compile(r'\{([^\{]*)title([^\}]*)\}', re.I)
authorExp = re.compile(r'\{([^\{]*)author([^\}]*)\}', re.I)
timestampExp = re.compile(r'\{([^\{]*)timestamp([^\}]*)\}', re.I)

title = "10 things on my todo list"
author = "Brandon"
timestamp = "2018-01-01 00:00:01"

match = re.search(titleExp, templateString)
title = '{}{}{}'.format(match.groups()[0], title, match.groups()[1])
templateString = re.sub(titleExp, title, templateString)

match = re.search(authorExp, templateString)
author = '{}{}{}'.format(match.groups()[0], author, match.groups()[1])
templateString = re.sub(authorExp, author, templateString)

match = re.search(timestampExp, templateString)
timestamp = '{}{}{}'.format(match.groups()[0], timestamp, match.groups()[1])
templateString = re.sub(timestampExp, timestamp, templateString)

print templateString

# output:
# 10 things on my todo list - Brandon (2018-01-01 00:00:01)
```